# Can't find is.wholenumber() function

Tags: r

I've got a weird problem with R. I'm trying this:

```
is.wholenumber(5)
```

and I get

> Error: could not find function "is.wholenumber"

I don't understand what the problem is. It's a basic function which is even referred to in: `help(is.integer)` so it should be there without needing additional downloading or special way of using?!?

Answer (score 7):

```
library("FRACTION")
is.wholenumber(5)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

`is.wholenumber()` is not a base function, but rather one defined in the example as so:

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) {
    abs(x - round(x)) < tol
}
```

You can type that in and then it will be a function.